# Dates month names language in Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, datetime

I have a `varchar` field in my table which contains a date, formatted as: `Dic 31 1999 12:00AM`, which can generally be converted without any problems using a `to_date` configuring `'Mon DD YYYY HH:MIAM'`.

Month names can of course come in any language. For instance, January, would be `Jan` in English and `Ene` in Spanish.

I reckon the Oracle client will pick up the machine's locale to figure which is the language of the incoming string. The only problem is that this will not always work if you are a server where you can't really know where the date is coming from.

My current problem is that every time I'm in a Spanish set computer and try to process a date with English named months, I'll get an "invalid month" error.

Is there I way I could tell Oracle, on execution time, which is the language I'm sending?

The current ugly workaround is to translate not matching months to Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` to determine you current language settings (also `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS` and `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` exist).

Use [`NLS_*`](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/globalization.html) environment variables on your workstation or `ALTER SESSION` statements within your SQL session to change these language settings.

Answer (score 14):

You should use NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE for that:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'dd Month, Day', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = turkish') from dual
```

Comment: Neat, you can do it this way without altering the session. Even better than the acepted answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER SESSION might work. I don't remember exactly how, but I know you can set locales, date styles and number formats with it.